# call function in dojo template widget from another dojo template widget

Tags: javascript, dojo

I need to call a function in a dojo template widget from another dojo template widget.  The problem is I need to call this function as if it were a static function, without creating a new instance of the template -- is there anyway to do this?  In my app Template 1 is a datagrid, and Template 2 is a form opened by clicking the row in the datagrid.  I need to refresh the datagrid based on actions taken in the form

Thanks

```
   Start Page:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.10/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.10/js/esri/css/esri.css">

  <script>
    var dojoConfig = {
    parseOnLoad:true,
    async: true,
    isDebug:true,
    packages: [
     {name: "Scripts", location: location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, "") + "/Scripts"}
    ]

};
</script>
  <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.10/"></script>

    <script>
        require(["Scripts/Mod1", "Scripts/Mod2"],
        function (Mod1, Mod2) {
            M1 = new Mod1();
            M1.M1Method("call from main page");
           // Mod1.M1Method("call from main page");//any way to make so this could work like static function?
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <div>look here you</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Template 1:

```
define(["Scripts/Mod2", "dojo/_base/declare", "dijit/_WidgetBase"],
 function (Mod2, declare, _WidgetBase) {
     return declare([_WidgetBase], {
         M1Method: function (msg) {
             alert(msg);
             M2 = new Mod2();
             M2.M2Method("call from Mod1"); //works great
             // Mod2.M2Method("call from Mod1"); //any way to make so this could work like static function?
         },
         M1Method2: function (msg) {
             alert(msg);
         }
     }
 )
 }
);
```

Template 2:

```
define(["require", "dojo/_base/declare", "dijit/_WidgetBase"],
 function (require, declare, _WidgetBase) {
     return declare([_WidgetBase], {
         M2Method: function (msg) {
             alert(msg);
             try {
                 require(["Scripts/Mod1"], function (Mod1) {
                     M1 = new Mod1();
                     M1.M1Method2("call from Mod2");
                     //Mod1.M1Method2("call from Mod2");//any way to make so this could work like static function?
                 });
             } catch (dohObj) {
                 alert(dohObj.message);
             }
         }
     }
 )
 }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're actual question is, but if you want to create "static methods", then yes, it's possible. Just add them after the `declare()` statement, like this:

```
var M1 = declare([_WidgetBase], {
    /** Your code */
});
M1.M1Method = function(msg) {
    /** Your static method */
};
return M1;
```

However, please note that if you create a static method, it is not available when you create an instance, for example the following will work:

```
M1.M1Method("test");
```

But this won't work any longer:

```
var m = new M1();
m.M1Method("test");
```

---

If you want to create a method that is both available as part of the prototype AND as a "static method", then you can write something like this:

```
/** An object containing your "static methods" */
var statics = {
    static: function (msg) {
        console.log("Static:" + msg);
    }
};

/** Your actual prototype */
var M1 = declare([], lang.mixin({
    nonStatic: function (msg) {
        console.log("Non static:" + msg);
    }
}, statics));
/** Mixin the statics */
lang.mixin(M1, statics);
return M1;
```

So, we're using `dojo/_base/lang::mixin()` here to mix the static object twice, first we're using it to mix it into the prototype, so you can still access the method when you're having an instance and then we mix it into the result as well.

I've setup a basic example on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/FE9Qz/